# Using Spatie/Browsershot with laravel. Injected HTML is rendering correctly when in Chrome, but not in Browsershot

Tags: php, css, laravel, puppeteer, spatie-browsershot

I have a laravel app that reads a webpage, replaces all relative URLs with absolute URLs from the original webpage and returns the HTML.

This works well and exactly how I want.  Trying to also grab a screenshot of the resulting rendered HTML using spatie/Browsershot (which uses Puppeteer via headless Chrome browser).

The result of the screenshot shows that the CSS is not being rendered.

The code in question looks like this:

```
 //Create Screenshot 
 $browserShot = Browsershot::html($html);
 $browserShot->setChromePath(config('browsershot.chrome_path'))->setOption('args', ['--disable-web-security'])->waitUntilNetworkIdle()->emulateMedia(null)->fullPage()->save($fileName.".png");

// Output HTML content
return $html;
```

The HTML returned to the user gets rendered fine by Chrome. But for some reason in the headless chrome browser it is not picking up the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the default userAgent.  After updating that rendering works as expected:

```
//Create Screenshot
 $browserShot = Browsershot::html($boundingBoxHtml);
 $browserShot->setChromePath(config('browsershot.chrome_path'))->waitUntilNetworkIdle()->userAgent($userAgent)->emulateMedia('screen')->fullPage()->save($fileName.".png");
```